# How to load multiple google maps dynamically in bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps

I have multiple listings on a page with a hyperlink that opens a modal window with a map in it. The code is identical to what we have here:

http://www.bootply.com/zhqU9Vhu4k

The javascript I am using is:

```
var map;        
var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(53, -1.33);
var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
    position:myCenter
});

function initialize() {
  var mapProp = {
      center:myCenter,
      zoom: 14,
      draggable: false,
      scrollwheel: false,
      mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),mapProp);
  marker.setMap(map);

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

    infowindow.setContent(contentString);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);

  }); 
};
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", resizeMap());

$('#myMapModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
   resizeMap();
});


function resizeMap() {
   if(typeof map =="undefined") return;
   var center = map.getCenter();
   google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
   map.setCenter(center); 
};
```

How can I load a different map in the modal for each link by making use of the data attribute (to pass the latitude and longitude values)?

**Edit:** I would prefer to not add any additional markup to this page as there are about 100 listings.

Comment: Use Different ID for new Maps..

Comment: That would mean additional markup for each modal. Can it be done without using the unique ids?

Comment: Yeah we can do like this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the center (as mentioned) as `data`-attribute for the links, e.g.:

```
<a href="#myMapModal" class="btn" data-center='{&quot;lat&quot;:52.52,&quot;lng&quot;:13.4}" data-toggle="modal">Berlin</a>

<a href="#myMapModal" class="btn" data-center="{&quot;lat&quot;:35.68,&quot;lng&quot;:139.69}" data-toggle="modal">Tokio</a>

<a href="#myMapModal" class="btn" data-center="{&quot;lat&quot;:55.75,&quot;lng&quot;:37.61}" data-toggle="modal">Moscow</a>
```

(Note the special format of the `data-center`-attribute, when you set it this way...as JSON... it may be used directly as `LatLngLiteral` when you access it via `$.data`, no further parsing is required )

In the `shown`-handler you may pass this attribute(`LatLngLiteral`) to `resizeMap`:

```
$('#myMapModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(e) {

   resizeMap($(e.relatedTarget).data('center'));

});
```

finally the modified `resizeMap`-function

```
function resizeMap(center) {

   if(typeof map =="undefined") return;
   google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
   map.setCenter(center); 

};
```

Demo: [**http://www.bootply.com/UG8DzfpeWO**](http://www.bootply.com/UG8DzfpeWO)

Comment: Precisely what I was after. Cheers.

Comment: Just implemented it. Everything works OK but the marker isn't showing up at the center. Is there a way to set marker on the go (resizeMap) just like you did with setCenter ?